# Remove zero-padding from unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, emoji

I want to get the unicode representation of an Emoji.

With the following snippet I can get it

```
emoji_rep = unicode('', 'utf-8').encode('unicode_escape')
```

The value of `emoji_rep` is `\U0001f605`
However, I just want the result to be `1f605`. Is there an pythonic/elegant way to solve this? Also, some emojis have unicode values such as `\u270b\U0001f3fe`. A nicer way to represent it would be `270b+1f3fe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the code point with `ord(u'')`. If you want you can then convert it to hex: eg. via `hex(ord(u''))` or `"{:x}".format(ord(u''))`.

Note the most common hex representation of Unicode code points is `U+270B` (4 digits) for code points below 0x10000 and `U+01F3FE` (6 digits) for the others.

Comment: I get a `TypeError` since `ord()` expects a single character, but an Emoji is a string.

Comment: @Hashirun: don't use non-ascii bytestring literals (they are even explicitly forbidden in Python 3 and it is a good practice to avoid them on Python 2 too). Use Unicode literals instead: `u''`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry, I'm confused. So I tried `ord(u'')` and get `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found`.

Comment: @Hashirun: it means you are using a narrow python 2 build where non-BMP characters are represented as utf-16 surrogates (`u'\ud83d\ude05'`). It is an implementation artifact. If you can't use a wide python build (Linux) or upgrade to Python 3 then you have to use a workaround.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh. Ok, good to know. I just upgraded my Django project to `Python 3.5`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just ran into a different problem with more complicated emojis like  or  (which is basically just+ \U+1F3FE). Can you point me to a workaround for those, which are not a single character? And yes, I'm already running Python 3.5, and thought that Python can hold an emoji in a single character.

Comment: What is wrong with `"+".join([u'{:x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u'\U0001F3FE'])`? Write down an example input, the desired output, describe using words what is your current issue and add a minimal but complete code example that shows the issue and either update your question or post a new one.

Comment: Sorry for bothering. I just figured it out. I can just call `hex(ord(u''[0]))` which is basically what I want anyway.

Comment: @Hashirun `''`, *U+01F1E6 REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A* is not an emoji on it's own. **The two code points together** encode a country flag emoji. `''` is the flag of Anguilla.